# vsphere API - searchManagedEntity function always returns null

Tags: virtualization, vsphere, esxi

The `searchManagedEntity` function always returns null, I've tried many solutions on the web but unfortunately none of them worked.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```java
ServiceInstance serviceInstance = authentification.connexionExsi();
Folder rootFolder = serviceInstance.getRootFolder();
System.out.println("Host" + (HostSystem) new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder).searchManagedEntity("HostSystem","192.168.1.44"));
```

Thank you in advance for your help <3

Comment: well i think i will never find a solution to this problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've finally found the solution to this problem, you must use the name of ESXI host instead of the IP (ESXI Name = ESXI Hostname  + Domain Name):

code:

```
ServiceInstance serviceInstance =  authentification.connexionExsi();
Folder rootFolder = serviceInstance.getRootFolder();
System.out.println("Host"+new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder).searchManagedEntity("HostSystem","rabatos.Home").getName());
```

you can find the host & domain name in Dns & Routing, as depicted in the picture below:

[Esxi Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwu6d.png)